# Dynamically updating PayPal currency and amount fields using javascript function

Tags: javascript, dom, paypal

I am trying to dynamically update the amount and currency value fields in the following PayPal Buy Now form based on the radio button selection using the function below. I am unable to get it to pass the currency and amount values to the form.

The form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" name="f" id="f">
<input name="audio-book" type="radio" class="sum" value="54.95" checked="checked" /> NZ$ 54.95
<input name="audio-book" type="radio" class="sum" value="43.95" /> AU$ 43.95
<input name="audio-book" type="radio" class="sum" value="45.00" /> US$ 45.00
<input name="audio-book" type="radio" class="sum" value="34.95" /> EU€ 34.95

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="NZ">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="xxxxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency_code" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="xxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="xxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" class="alignleft wp-image-2884 size-full" src="../uploads/btn_buynow_pp_142x27.png" border="0" name="submit1" id="button" onclick="javascript:doSubmit();" alt="PayPal - The safer...">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

and the function:

```
<script>
function doSubmit(){
var $cost=0;
var $code="";
var $currency=['NZD', 'AUD', 'USD', 'EUR'];

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('sum');

for (i = 0; i<parent.length; ++i){
if(parent[i].checked === true){
cost = Number(parent[i].value);
code = currency[i];}
}

document.getElementById('amount').value = cost;
document.getElementById('currency_code').value = code;
document.getElementById('f').submit();
return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your inputs are being referenced by getElementById but do not have an ID attribute.

Comment: Hi David, I have ID attributes on the currency_code and amount fields in the form.

Comment: Oops my mistake, where is the javascript included in the page?

Comment: Directly under the form

Comment: I think the issue is the form is submitting before your function is firing with the button press, I would move the function into the form submit, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like everything is fine with the code . The only thing you need to change in the script is the below line :

Currently you have :

```
code = currency[i];
```

Change it to :

```
code = $currency[i];
```

I just tried it at my end and it worked .

Comment: Hi Eshan, yes that worked. Good skills and many thanks.

Thank you David for your help also.
kind regards to you both Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Please have look at my sample fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ghtgggb2/

Couple of things

- move the script to the bottom (not sure where it is in your HTML)
- move the function to the form for testing `onsubmit="return doSubmit()"`

Comment: Hi David, I did have a look and very much appreciate your efforts with jsfiddle. However, the problem was resolved by adding the $ to the currency variable as suggested by Eshan above.